# Implement Single Signon in Windows without Azure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, single-sign-on

I am working in C# on a web application that requires a login username and password. This application is made to be compatible with Windows and is being written in VS 2013. In this company's network, all computers require user credentials, and in all cases the user's credentials for the app will be the same as their Windows logon credentials. Therefore we are trying to implement a system where, instead of signing onto Windows and then entering the same credentials again in the app, the app can access the Windows credentials that were given by the current user and attempt to sign in automatically with those. I know there is a way to do this using active directory with Azure, but for the time being we are trying to avoid using Azure. I have tried using `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` and `Environment.UserName` so far, but both of those only supply the username, not the password, and we need the full credentials. It wouldn't shock me if this cannot be done in this way for security purposes, but if there is a way it would be incredibly helpful. Does anyone know of a way to access the current user's credentials? Thanks

Comment: What kind of web application? The specifics vary, but both ASP.NET Web Forms and MVC support Windows authentication and role-based authorization through attributes, configuration settings or direct checks with `IsInRole`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Azure to accomplish this.  Your application pool simply needs to have Windows Authentication enabled.  You will not have access to the password, however.

After that, you will need to most likely write a `HttpHandler` which will get the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` value and check it against a database or collection of authorized users.  You don't need to "re-authenticate".

Comment: Terrific, thanks! :)
(It won't let me accept the answer yet, but once it does I'll mark it as answered)

Comment: No need for any HttpHandlers, role membership it's in the box since the first version of ASP.NET. Put the users to role-specific account groups and use `IsInRole` to check for membership. ASP.NET also allows authorization by role, through attributes and configuration settings

Comment: That's assuming he's using Active Directory for all application-specific group assignments, which hasn't been the case in any environment I've worked in.